# Difference between WebService and Remoting

Tags: c#, web-services, remoting

I was comparing Web service with Remoting from performance and interoperatibility point of views
and have some doubts regarding it.

1) As Remoting support both TCP and HTTP channel, so is it when use TCP channel 
It uses binary formatting and when HTTP, SOAP formatting

2) Can we use binary formating with HTTP protocol and XML/Soap formatting using TCP Protocol in Remoting

3) As Remoting supports XML/SOAP formatting which is universally accepted for any technology
and platform so it should provide interoperatibility between Server/client applications of
any technology/platform and if provide then what is use of web service. 
As per my knowledge main advantage of Webservice over remoting is interoperatibility.

4) If I use Remoting with SOAP and HTTP, is it get bypassed by internet firewalls same way
as for web service or, still get restricted by firewalls.

5) Is any performance variation still exist if use remoting with SOAP formatting over
HTTP and webservice with SOAP formatting over Http.

6) Whether webservice support binary formatting and TCP Protocol as per my understanding
webservice only supports http prtocol but as per some programmers opinion in stack overflow 
webservice is independent of transport protocol, so Is it like asp.net webservice only works on
http and web service developed in other technologies supports both TCP and HTTP.

Regards,
Arun Patil

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426249/what-is-the-difference-between-web-service-and-remoting and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507862/net-remoting-vs-web-services-vs-windows-communication-foundation-wcf

Comment: I can be wrong but to my understanding/memories classic XML Web services ARE using .NET Remoting behind the scenes while WCF services don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Remoting in HTTP mode, you WILL get past the firewalls.

While these two might seem they are doing the same thing, they are two different beasts. As an example, you can use interface types in Remoting, e.g. a service returning an interface, while this is not possible using ASMX Webservices (older stack) or WCF (only partially supported by KnownTypes), but on the other hand WCF supports multiple endpoints/bindings and better security and extensibility model than Remoting.

My advice would be if you are on a project already using Remoting, stick with it, otherwise it would not be a very wise choice to go with a technology that is, if not obsolete, won't get any new features so I'd suggest WCF for a green field project.