# Difference between .Net Remoting and Web Service for XML encoding and Http Communication

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, remoting

MSDN says about Remoting as :-

Formatters are used for encoding and decoding the messages before they are transported by the channel. Applications can use binary encoding where performance is critical, or XML encoding where interoperability with other remoting frameworks is essential. All XML encoding uses the SOAP protocol in transporting messages from one application domain to the other.

Defination in MSDN says Remoting can be used for interoperatibility and in such cases data is encoded into XML Messsage using SOAP protocol and transmitted over HTTP. As this behavior of Remoting makes it inter operable, what benefit or feature web service brings in Service Oriented Architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to WebServices vs Remoting then Web Service have less functionality in comparison to Remoting like in Remoting you have Callbacks,Sponser Time, Lease Time etc but SOAP protocol is available with WebServices only. Remoting is mainly for TCP IP Protocols or Intranet application when it comes to HTTP and HTTPS communication remoting can be used but Firewall need to be taken care.

Check out this link

[Difference between WebService and Remoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791939/difference-between-webservice-and-remoting)

or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978420.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If both are using XML formatter and HTTP protocol then I think the only difference would be that you can use interface types in Remoting i.e. Service can return an interface which would be very helpful if your provider and consumer environments are using .net for development.